# Kernel compilation fails against "spl-dkms_*.deb" package not found!

Tags: package-management, kernel

I'm attempting to compile the kernel using [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) but I got an error.

```
cp -rp "/home/stibbons/build/ubuntu-disco/debian/linux-headers-5.0.0-15-generic/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-15-generic" "/home/stibbons/build/ubuntu-disco/debian/linux-headers-5.0.0-15/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-15" "/home/stibbons/build/ubuntu-disco/debian/build/build-generic/___________________________________dkms/headers"
/bin/bash -e debian/scripts/dkms-build /home/stibbons/build/ubuntu-disco/debian/build/build-generic/___________________________________dkms 5.0.0-15-generic '  /home/stibbons/build/ubuntu-disco/debian/build/build-generic/scripts/sign-file sha512 /home/stibbons/build/ubuntu-disco/debian/build/build-generic/certs/signing_key.pem /home/stibbons/build/ubuntu-disco/debian/build/build-generic/certs/signing_key.x509'  linux-modules-5.0.0-15-generic  /home/stibbons/build/ubuntu-disco/debian/linux-modules-5.0.0-15-generic/lib/modules/5.0.0-15-generic/kernel  spl  pool/universe/s/spl-linux/spl-dkms__all.deb
II: dkms-build downloading spl (spl-dkms__all.deb)
--2019-05-16 23:04:11--  https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/pool/universe/s/spl-linux/spl-dkms__all.deb
Resolving packagecloud.io (packagecloud.io)... 54.241.144.200, 52.9.242.175, 2600:1f1c:2e5:6901:4eff:41b9:710a:77ff, ...
Connecting to packagecloud.io (packagecloud.io)|54.241.144.200|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-05-16 23:04:11 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2019-05-16 23:04:12--  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/spl-linux/spl-dkms__all.deb
Resolving security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.152, 91.189.88.161, 91.189.88.162, ...
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-05-16 23:04:12 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2019-05-16 23:04:12--  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/spl-linux/spl-dkms__all.deb
Resolving security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.149, 91.189.91.26, 91.189.91.23, ...
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.149|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-05-16 23:04:12 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2019-05-16 23:04:12--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/spl-linux/spl-dkms__all.deb
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.23, 91.189.91.26, 2001:67c:1562::19
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.23|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-05-16 23:04:13 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2019-05-16 23:04:13--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/spl-linux/spl-dkms__all.deb
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.26, 91.189.91.23, 2001:67c:1562::19
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-05-16 23:04:13 ERROR 404: Not Found.

dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive 'spl-dkms_*.deb': No such file or directory
make: *** [debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:219: install-generic] Error 2
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

**@RedHatter** I ran into this same issue and traced the failure to the version string parsing code in debian/rules which relies on gawk.

```
# Versions of dkms packages.
dkms_zfs_linux_version=$(shell gawk '/^zfs-linux / { print $$2; }' debian/dkms-versions)
dkms_spl_linux_version=$(shell gawk '/^spl-linux / { print $$2; }' debian/dkms-versions)
dkms_nvidia_version=$(shell gawk '/^nvidia-graphics-drivers-/ { print $$2; }' debian/dkms-versions)
```

As I was compiling this on a fresh install of Kubuntu, gawk was not available by default, causing a silent failure.

The fix for me was easy, `sudo apt install gawk` before starting your build.

Answer (score 0):

On my PC it was due to a missing package, the reason being that the guide instructs to run:

`sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev flex bison openssl-dev libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev`

which fails because the package "openssl-dev" does not exist on recent versions of Ubuntu, and then none of the packages get installed. Therefore you need to run the command without openssl-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev flex bison libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install spl-dkms
```